# What semantic notions inverted the meaning of 'with' (from opposition to association)?

Tags: etymology, latin, old-norse, prepositions

> [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with#Etymology_1) :] From Middle English [with](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with#Middle_English), from Old English [wiþ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wi%C3%BE#Old_English) ‎(“against, opposite, toward”), a shortened form of wiþer, from Proto-Germanic *wiþr- ‎(“against”), from Proto-Indo-European *wi-tero- ‎(“more apart”); from Proto-Indo-European *wi ‎(“separation”).      [...]
>
> [[Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=with&allowed_in_frame=0), which appears to have extracted from [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229612?rskey=aRqnsd&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid14158565) :]     [...]      Sense shifted in Middle English to denote association, combination, and union, partly by influence of Old Norse *vidh*, and also perhaps by Latin *cum* "with" (as in pugnare cum "fight with").     [...]

History confirms that enemies (who are separate from, and who fight, each other) can become friends (who must be associated and united);
1. but what semantic notions explain, conciliate and underlie the polar opposites of association and opposition? Does my facile conjecture really explain the enormity of this semantic inversion?

2. How did the Old Norse *vidh* and Latin *cum* influence the Semantic Shift of 'with'?

Comment: "Fighting with" is so ambiguous!

Answer (score 2):

One of the many meanings of Old Norse **við** was "nearby, close to" and another was "in the company of" or "in the presence of". For the Norse speaker, it also meant "against, towards".   See *An Icelandic-English Dictionary* 2nd edition (Oxford 1957).

There were many Norse speakers in England; large areas of the country were peopled (often mainly) with Scandinavians. English shows much Norse influence. Over the course of generations the language of English speakers would gradually accommodate the new meaning as the peoples had business dealings, became neighbors, and intermarried.

You might wish to read what the *Middle English Dictionary* has to say about "[with](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED52999)".

Comment: Thanks, as always. Can you please explain the underlying semantic notions in Old Norse that connect `against, towards` with `nearby, close to` and `"in the company of"`? I read the Middle English Dictionary's entry but it does not reveal the underlying semantic notions.

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Comment: The word already had those meanings in Old Norse, where they distinguished or marked by the grammatical case of the indirect object (dative [towards, against] versus accusative [proximity, company,accompaniment, association, togetherness]).

Comment: typo: ...where they were distinguished...

Comment: But how did the word already have those meanings in Old Norse?

Comment: I don't know "how" the words have those meanings in Old Norse, only *that* they have those meanings.  Proto-Germanic is reconstructed from the various Germanic branches; the northern branch attests to these meanings. I do not see the meanings as "polar opposites". From *facing towards* to  *in the company of* is just a bit of a hop, not a major leap. The more interesting question is how in ON **við** acquired its instrumental meaning: "He crossed the lake *við swimming*" [semi-translated]

Comment: Thanks. I presented the above question on ON: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/19128/5306